# How to find out: Are all commits in a given branch covered by a pull request?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

our internally used development process demands that we formally prove that all commits that were pushed are covered by a review (=pull request).

I know that if we would have enabled branch protection since the beginning of existence of a repo and its branches no commit can be pushed to the protected branches without a review/pull request.

Our internal auditors unfortunately are not satisfied with only looking at pull requests and telling them "The process does not allow to not cover a commit with a review".

Any idea how this could be accomplished? Can I fetch all the data via REST API and create a report on my own or is there something already existing, did not find anything in that direction in the web ui.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out extension [Pull Request Manager Hub](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=caribeiro84.pull-request-manager-hub). It can list your Pull Requests of all your projects and repositories at a single place.

After you install this extension in your organization. You can go the **Pull Request Manager Hub** under **Repos** from your Azure devops Project UI page to check out the **reviewers**, **status** and other details of the PR. See below:

[image]

You can also use rest api to get all the data and create a report on your own. See below [Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId or repositoryName}/pullrequests?api-version=5.1`

To get the reviewers you can use [Pull Request Reviewers - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20reviewers/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api.

See below example scripts in powershell to [call rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops). Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to get a personal access token.

```
$url ="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId or repositoryName}/pullrequests?api-version=5.1"

$pat = "Personal Access Token"    

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$PRs=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get -ContentType "application/json" 

$PRs.value | select pullRequestId, reviewers
```

Comment: It is not the perfect solution I was hoping to get but it is definitely very helpful. Thanks.